# Rails javascript buttons causing post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created a form where a user can move items from the left side to the right side using two buttons.  After the user has finished adding their items they can name & save the group.  At least that's how it's supposed to work.  Instead, as soon as I add one item, and click on the 'move right'  button the POST action fires.  Why are my javascript driven buttons firing the POST action instead of the `submit_tag`?

Here's what the form looks like `view/settings/global.html.erb`:

[image]

The form code in the view:

```
<%= form_tag '/create_host_group', id: "host_group_form", class: "form-horizontal" do %>

  <%= label_tag "Group Name", nil, required: true, class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'host_group_name', nil, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= label_tag "Available Hosts", nil, class: "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" %>
  <select id="hosts_available" class="form-control" size="30" multiple>
     <% @network_hosts.each do |n| %>
        <option value="<%= n.id %>"><%= n.ip_address %></option>
     <% end %>
  </select>

  <button id="btnRight" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-forward"></i></button>
  <br/>
  <button id="btnLeft" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-backward"></i></button>

  <select id="hosts_assigned" class="form-control" size="30" multiple></select>

  <%= submit_tag "Add Group", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>

<script>
  $("#btnLeft").click(function(){
    var selectedItem = $("#hosts_assigned option:selected");
    $("#hosts_available").append(selectedItem);
  });

  $("#btnRight").click(function(){
    var selectedItem = $("#hosts_available option:selected");
    $("#hosts_assigned").append(selectedItem);
  });
</script>
```

In my controller for loading the view `settings_controller.rb`:

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_company_and_locations

  def global
    get_network_hosts
  end

end
```

The POST action is calling `network_host_groups_controller#create`, which I'm just trying to debug right now:

```
class NetworkHostGroupsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    group_name = params[:host_group_name]
    assigned_hosts = params[:hosts_assigned]
    puts "#{group_name}: #{assigned_hosts}"
  end

end
```

And my routes are:

```
match '/global_settings', to: 'settings#global', via: 'get'
match '/create_host_group', to: 'network_host_groups#create', via: 'post'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button elements default to [submit](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/button.html) on click.

Add a `type="button"` attribute to indicate to the browser that clicking the button shouldn't submit the form!

```
<button type="button" id="btnRight" class="btn btn-success">
```

Comment: You can also change your javascript `click` handlers to `return false` or call [`preventDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), which will prevent the default action. But @j-dexx's approach is the cleanest!